# How do I reinterpret_cast between any two types?

Tags: c++, c++11, reinterpret-cast

I would like to re-declare the type of a given variable, but unfortunately reinterpret_cast<> does not help here. This line:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::vector<double>>(std::string("Hello"));
```

results in the following compiler error:

```
invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'std::vector<double>'
```

Is there a different, clean approach?

Notes:

- I know that reinterpret_cast<> is not a proper conversion. I really do only want to re-declare the type here. Some code around this line will make sure it is only performed when appropriate
- Why actually does this line above not work?
- I am aware of this option, which I think is too messy: *reinterpret_cast(&OldType)

Edit/Some context: This line will be part of a templated function, with:

```
reinterpret_cast<T>(std::string())
```

For T == std::string this is completely fine, but unfortunately the compiler will also try to instantiate (but at runtime never use) it for T == std::vector<>. And this is C++11, so there is no static_if.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish here, and why do you think `reinterpret_cast` will help you accomplish this goal?

Comment: Yes, there is a different clean approach.  Make a routine that takes a `std::string` and constructs-and-returns a `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: _"Some code around this line will make sure it is only performed when appropriate"_ It's never appropriate, and certainly not with the examples you've given us.

Comment: @milleniumbug I need to make a template instance compile-able.No conversion intended, nothing is supposed to happen in memory. I need to deactivate the type check once

Comment: Sounds like what you _really_ need is some `enable_if` monstrosity using a "is-convertible" trait of some kind. It would really be better if you asked about your real problem rather than about this invalid solution

Comment: What makes you believe that `reinterpret_cast<std::string>(std::string())` is "completely fine"?

Comment: Hint: [it isn't](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad57bf1c3c8ec811). There are some misconceptions surrounding conversions here, I think!

Comment: @molbdnilo, well this was exactly my question (note 2). Why would it not be fine? reintepret_cast<> as per standard does not alter the values in memory

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<std::string>` is not covered by any of the [allowed casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). `std::string` is not a reference type, nor is it a integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit,there are already a couple of enable_ifs in the code base and your suggestion would work, but I can assure you it will not make it transparent.

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question; your _real_ one.

Comment: @JonnDove "For T == std::string this is completely fine" is not a question, it is a statement of fact (and it is not true). And no conversions, whether implicit or explicit, ever alter any values; they create new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For T == std::string this is completely fine, but unfortunately the compiler will also try to instantiate (but at runtime never use) it for T == std::vector<>. And this is C++11, so there is no static_if.

In C++17, as you said, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& value)
{
    bar(value);

    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::string, T>::value) {
        // Specific code for string
    } else constexpr (std::is_same<std::vector<int>, T>::value) {
        // specific code for vector...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Prior to C++17, you might use overloads, potentially with tag dispatching, SFINAE.

```
void foo_specific(const std::string& s)
{
    // Specific code for string
}

void foo_specific(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    // Specific code for vector
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>, int> = 0>
void foo_specific(const T& n)
{
    // Specific code for integral
}

// ...

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& value)
{
    bar(value);

    foo_specific(value);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't, it makes no sense to do so, and the compiler told you that.

`reinterpret_cast` can't hack a type into an entirely unrelated type.

Even if it did, such as with the pointer hackery you exhibit in your final bullet point, the language's rules prohibit you from using an object that's undergone such a cast.

Simply don't do it, because you can't.

If you're trying to construct a vector of doubles from a string (?), then do exactly that, writing the appropriate code to produce doubles from your string, in the manner proscribed by your business requirements.

The type system is there to help you. Let it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me. I added some more context above.

Comment: I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct a container from a string literal.

Use a different constructor overload, e.g.

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Which is compatible with

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Thusly

```
char hello[] = "Hello";
T{ std::begin(hello), std::end(hello) }
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8b8fef24774923)